# PHP Regex to grab a parameter value

Tags: php, regex

Technically I need to implement parse_str() using regex. Though I will only extract one parameter value from a query. 
I have a string like 
`a=val1&b=val2&c=val3`

is it possible to get only the value of say `b` using preg_match also assuming b can be the last query (means the string can also be `a=val1&b=val2`)?

Comment: Stupid question: why can't you use parse_str() ? It's there since php 4

Comment: Is there any particular reason you have to use regex?

Comment: yes actually, I have to use a modified version of PHP 5.3 and it strips off html tags for parse_str() call which I need to retain using my own parse_str() implementation. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems simple enough:

```
/(?:^|&)b=([^&]*)/
```

The value you want will be in the first capture group.